# Torque installation error: @sbindir@/trqauthd: No such file or Directory

Tags: batch-processing, job-scheduling, pbs, rhel6, torque

I gave the following commands to install (in root login) the Torque:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

After that, I tried to run Torque daemon using:

```
cp contrib/init.d/trqauthd.in /etc/init.d/trqauthd
chkconfig --add trqauthd
echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/torque.conf
ldconfig
service trqauthd start
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Starting TORQUE Authorization Daemon: /bin/bash: @sbindir@/trqauthd: No such file or directory
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong file. You want the "`trqauthd`" file. `trqauthd.in` is the unprocessed pre-make file.